# How to store an outer array element to an array in JOLT?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, jolt

From the following example, I want to store the value of 'd' in a variable c

```
 {
  "d": "TESTING198",
  "test": [
    {
      "a": "text1",
      "testing": "TESTING198"
    },
    {
      "a": "text2",
      "testing": "TESTING198"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "d": "TESTING198",
  "test": [
    {
      "a": "text[&].testing"
    },
    {
      "a": "text[&].testing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,d)": "testing"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I think I made a mistake some where but not able to figure it out.

Comment: Your question is unclear.   What is the desired output?